# Watershed analysis for construction site

Tags: watershed

Watershed analysis pretty straight forward except I lose understanding when it comes to selecting the pour point at a point along a stream.

What if I have a construction site, what is my pour point?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: The whole site is your 'point'.

Comment: I am using Arc Map 10.3. my site is approximately 5 acres.